# VHDL Full adder with Mux 8:3

Tags: vhdl, mux, ghdl

I tried to create a full adder using a Mux8:3... but it doesn't run!
When I run it, I don't get any error from the command line, but GHDL doesn't start!

What can I do?

```
      -----------------------MUX8ingressi-------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux8 is
  port(
       A: in STD_LOGIC;
       B: in STD_LOGIC;
       C: in STD_LOGIC;
       D: in STD_LOGIC;
       E: in STD_LOGIC;
       F: in STD_LOGIC;
       G: in STD_LOGIC;
       H: in STD_LOGIC;
       S1: in STD_LOGIC;
       S2: in STD_LOGIC;
       S3: in STD_LOGIC;
       U: out STD_LOGIC
  );
end mux8;


architecture RTL of mux8 is
signal S: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);

  begin
    S <= S1&S2&S3;
    U <= A when S="000" else
         B when S="001" else
         C when S="010" else
         D when S="011" else
         E when S="100" else
         F when S="101" else
         G when S="110" else
         H;

  end RTL;

-------------------FULL ADDER-------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FA is
  port(
       add1: in STD_LOGIC;
       add2: in STD_LOGIC;
       Ci: in STD_LOGIC;
       S: out STD_LOGIC;
       Co: out STD_LOGIC
  );
end FA;

architecture RTL of FA is
--  Ci  A  B |  Co  S
-------------|---------
--   0  0  0 |   0  0
--   0  0  1 |   0  1
--   0  1  0 |   0  1
--   0  1  1 |   1  0
--   1  0  0 |   0  1
--   1  0  1 |   1  0
--   1  1  0 |   1  0
--   1  1  1 |   1  1

component mux8 is
  port(
       A: in STD_LOGIC;
       B: in STD_LOGIC;
       C: in STD_LOGIC;
       D: in STD_LOGIC;
       E: in STD_LOGIC;
       F: in STD_LOGIC;
       G: in STD_LOGIC;
       H: in STD_LOGIC;
       S1: in STD_LOGIC;
       S2: in STD_LOGIC;
       S3: in STD_LOGIC;
       U: out STD_LOGIC
  );
end component;

  begin
    test: mux8 port map (
                            A=>'0',
                            B=>'1',
                            C=>'1',
                            D=>'0',
                            E=>'1',
                            F=>'0',
                            G=>'0',
                            H=>'1',
                            S1=>add1,
                            S2=>add2,
                            S3=>Ci,
                            U=>S
                            );

  end RTL;

-----------------TEST BENCH-----------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FA_tb is
end FA_tb;


architecture test of FA_tb is
component FA is
  port(
       add1: in STD_LOGIC;
       add2: in STD_LOGIC;
       Ci: in STD_LOGIC;
       S: out STD_LOGIC;
       Co: out STD_LOGIC
  );
end component;

signal add1_tb, add2_tb, Ci_tb, S_tb, Co_tb: STD_LOGIC;
signal  ideal_co: STD_LOGIC;
signal  ideal_s: STD_LOGIC;
signal  ERRORE_S,ERRORE_Co: STD_LOGIC := '0';

begin

    UUT: FA port map (add1=>add1_tb, add2=>add2_tb, Ci=>Ci_tb, S=>S_tb, Co=>Co_tb);

    process
    begin
    add1_tb<='0'; add2_tb<='0'; Ci_tb<='0'; ideal_co<='0'; ideal_s<='0';
    wait for 10 ns;
    add1_tb<='0'; add2_tb<='1'; Ci_tb<='0'; ideal_co<='0'; ideal_s<='1';
    wait for 10 ns;
    add1_tb<='1'; add2_tb<='0'; Ci_tb<='0'; ideal_co<='0'; ideal_s<='1';
    wait for 10 ns;
    add1_tb<='1'; add2_tb<='1'; Ci_tb<='0'; ideal_co<='1'; ideal_s<='0';
    wait for 10 ns;
    add1_tb<='0'; add2_tb<='0'; Ci_tb<='1'; ideal_co<='0'; ideal_s<='1';
    wait for 10 ns;
    add1_tb<='0'; add2_tb<='1'; Ci_tb<='1'; ideal_co<='1'; ideal_s<='0';
    wait for 10 ns;
    add1_tb<='1'; add2_tb<='0'; Ci_tb<='1'; ideal_co<='1'; ideal_s<='0';
    wait for 10 ns;
    add1_tb<='1'; add2_tb<='1'; Ci_tb<='1'; ideal_co<='1'; ideal_s<='1';
    wait for 10 ns;

    wait;
    end process;

end test;
```

And now my *make.bat* file:

```
echo off
cls
set path=%path%;C:\Program files\GHDL\bin;C:\Program files\GHDL\gtk\bin;

echo on
ghdl -a FAconMUX_83.vhdl
ghdl -e mux8
ghdl -e FA
ghdl -e FA_tb
ghdl -r FA_tb --vcd=out83.vcd
gtkwave out83.vcd
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the commands you are using to compile, elaborate and run the simulation please?

Comment: I tried your code in ghdl on Linux, and it analyses, compiles and runs ok. I didn't check the VCD file in gtkwave, but a VCD file is generated and it does contain some activity. You should check your ghdl installation, that is probably at fault here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles fine. I tried it using [Altera Quartus II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quartus_Prime) 14.0 on [Windows 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8). I recommend that you use another synthesis tool, or just use logic gates to get both sum and carry.